# Sending a PyCharm project to someone

Tags: python, pycharm

I just finished working on a PyCharm project (using python 3.7), which uses libraries downloaded using PyCharm's built in functionality.  I just want to send this project to my boss so that he can simply run it by clicking on it, without having to go through downloading PyCharm and downloading the applicable packages.  Please tell me that there is a way to do this.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert your python project to a program exucutable in windows you can use the library pyinstaller.

**install the library:**
pip install pyinstaller

then in the path of the project,open a command console and type the following commands.

if you want the executable in one file(slower start):
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon="your_icon_file".ico "your_python_script".py

if you want the executable in one folder(faster start):
pyinstaller.exe --onedir --windowed --icon="your_icon_file".ico "your_python_script".py

this wil create a folder call "dist" where your .exe will be,

pd: whith the --onedir command you will see all your dependencies in that folder, if you have a simple script you can use the first option.

Link to the pyinstaller documentation:https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this issue by converting the .py file to an executable file or .exe file....

Hopefully it helped..thx

Comment: I've been looking into that, but I can't find a way to do that either

Comment: there is a youtube channel called tech with tim

Comment: He made a video on this... Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to that would be sharing it on github with a requirements.txt file containing all the dependencies which then can be installed using `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Or You can use `pyinstaller --onefile <yourfile.py>` to create a .exe file which could be run without any requirements on windows.